# Proximal operator of spectral norm (Schatten norm) of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, spectral-norm, proximal-operators

I would like to calculate the proximal operator of spectral norm for any general matrix, $X \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, i.e.,

$$X^* = \arg \min_X \|X\|_2 + \frac{1}{2\tau} \|X-Y\|_F^2$$

I understand that the proximal operator for nuclear norm $\|X\|_*$ is computed using the Singular Value Thresholding (SVT) algorithm, which is similar to the $\ell_1$-norm on a vector of singular values. Thus can we assume that proximal operator for spectral norm can also be similarly computed by taking the $\ell_{\infty}$-norm on a singular value vector ?

Comment: It may be a language issue, but it is *not* the case that "singular value thresholding... is similar to the $\ell_1$-norm on a vector of singular values." The correct thing to say is that the *proximal operator of the spectral norm* is similar to the *proximal operator of the $\ell_1$-norm.* And if you express it that way, then yes, the proximal operator of the spectral norm is similar to the proximal operator of the $\ell_\infty$ norm.

Comment: See [this paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/prox_algs.pdf), section 6.7.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, for any [Schatten Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) the algorithm is pretty simple.

If we use Capital Letter $ A $ for Matrix and Small Letter for Vector then:

$$ {\operatorname*{Prox}}_{\lambda \left\| \cdot \right\|_{p}} \left( A \right) = \arg \min_{X} \frac{1}{2} \left\| X - A \right\|_{F}^{2} + \lambda \left\| X \right\|_{p} $$

Where $ \left\| X \right\|_{p} $ is the $ p $ [Schatten Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm) of $ X $.

Defining $\boldsymbol{\sigma} \left( X \right) $ as a vector of the Singular Values of $ X $ (See the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition)), then the Proximal Operator Calculation is as following:

1. Apply the SVD on $ A $: $ A \rightarrow U \operatorname*{diag} \left( \boldsymbol{\sigma} \left( A \right) \right) {V}^{T} $.
2. Extract the vector of Singular Values $ \boldsymbol{\sigma} \left( A \right) $.
3. Calculate the Proximal Operator of the extracted vector using Vector Norm $ p $: $ \hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}} \left( A \right) = {\operatorname*{Prox}}_{\lambda \left\| \cdot \right\|_{p}} \left( \boldsymbol{\sigma} \left( A \right) \right) = \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} \left\| x - \boldsymbol{\sigma} \left( A \right) \right\|_{2}^{2} + \lambda \left\| x \right\|_{p} $.
4. Return the Proximal of the Matrix Norm: $ \hat{A} = {\operatorname*{Prox}}_{\lambda \left\| \cdot \right\|_{p}} \left( A \right) = U \operatorname*{diag} \left( \hat{\boldsymbol{\sigma}} \left( A \right) \right) {V}^{T} $.

The mapping of [Matrix Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) into [Schatten Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm):

- Frobenius Norm - Given by $ p = 2 $ in [Schatten Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm).
- Nuclear Norm - Given by $ p = 1 $ in [Schatten Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm).
- Spectral Norm (The $ {L}_{2} $ Induced Norm of a Matrix) - Given by $ p = \infty $ in [Schatten Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm).

Comment: Note that in the case $p=2$ (Frobenius norm), a much simpler closed form of prox exists which doesn’t involve any SVD.

Comment: @LorenzoStella, Indeed. In that case it is much easier to solve it as we're dealing with vectors (Vectorize the matrices).