# Nuclear norm minimization of a matrix in the presence of non-negativity constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, nuclear-norm

Let $L$ and $R$ be $n \times n$ matrices. Consider the following minimization problem

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{L} = \min_{L \geq \mathbf{0}}  \mu\|\mathbf{L}\|_* + \dfrac{1}{2\lambda}\|\mathbf{L-R}\|_F^2
\end{equation}

By $\mathbf{L}$ $\geq$ 0 , i mean that i wish the entries of $\mathbf{L}$ to be non negative.
I know the solution can be obtained using the singular value thresholding of $\mathbf{R}$ when the non-negativity constraint on $\mathbf{L}$ is not present. But I can't figure out the change needed in order to satisfy the non-negativity constraint on $\mathbf{L}$.
Will simply setting the negative entries of $\mathbf{L}$ to zero work?
This link [How to solve this minimization problem involving the nuclear norm?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296159/how-to-solve-this-minimization-problem-involving-the-nuclear-norm) is about $\mathbf{L}$ being positive definite; my question is about the entries of $\mathbf{L}$ being non-negative. Can someone please answer this?

Comment: $L \succeq O$ is not a non-negativity constraint.

Comment: I want the entries in $\mathbf{L}$ to be non negative.. i did not mean $\mathbf{L}$ to be positive semi definite..

Comment: Can simply setting the negative entries of $\mathbf{L}$ to zero work?

Comment: @RyanCory-Wright The link talks about $\mathbf{L}$ being positive definite. My concern is different. I want the entries of  $\mathbf{L}$  to be non negative..