# Proximal operator of the nuclear norm with non-negativity constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nuclear-norm, proximal-operators

Let $\bf L$ and $\bf R$ be $n \times n$ matrices. Consider the following regularized least-squares problem

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{L} = \min_{\mathbf{L} \geq \mathbf{0}}  \mu \|\mathbf{L}\|_* + \dfrac{1}{2\lambda}\|\mathbf{L-R}\|_F^2
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{L} \geq \mathbf{0}$ denotes that the matrix $\bf L$ is [non-negative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonnegative_matrix).

When the non-negativity constraint on $\mathbf{L}$ is not present, I know the solution can be obtained using the singular value thresholding of $\mathbf{R}$. However, I can't figure out the change needed in order to satisfy the non-negativity constraint on $\mathbf{L}$. Will simply setting the negative entries of $\mathbf{L}$ to zero work?

I have checked the question [Least-squares with nuclear norm regularization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2296159) in which $\mathbf{L}$ is positive definite. However, my question is about the **entries** of $\mathbf{L}$ being non-negative. Can someone please answer this?

Comment: Royi, why are you imposing proximal operators on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Douglas-Rachford method, which minimizes $f(L) + g(L)$, where $f$ and $g$ are closed convex functions with proximal operators that can be evaluated efficiently. For this problem, you can take $f(L) = \mu \|L\|_*$ and $g(L) = I(L) + \frac{1}{2\lambda} \| L - R \|^2_F$, where $I(L) = 0$ if $L \geq 0$ and $I(L) = \infty$ otherwise.

Comment: And what happens when $\mathbf{f(L)}$ is not convex (weighted nuclear norm, for example)?

Comment: how to calculate the proximal of $\mathcal{g(L)}$ here?

Comment: Some recent papers have studied Douglas-Rachford for non-convex problems. I'd have to check to see what convergence results are available. But empirically, Douglas-Rachford has sometimes been observed to perform well on certain non-convex problems.

Comment: To evaluate the proximal operator of $g$, you can first write out the definition of the proximal operator explicitly, then combine the two quadratic terms by completing the square. At that point, you will see that all you need to do is set the negative entries of a particular matrix equal to zero.