# Proximal Operator of Matrix Norm

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, nonlinear-optimization, proximal-operators

How to calculate proximal operator of $$F(X,Y) = f(X,Y) + \lambda(||X||^2 + ||Y||^2)$$ where $X$ and $Y$ are matrices. The problem is to minimize the given function with respect to X and Y.Idea is i want to use proximal gradient descent.For that i need to calculate proximal operator of given function.

Comment: Have a look here - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2444238/33. All needed is someone to take care of your case which is the sum of two matrices.

Comment: The sum of two matrices is real problem.

Comment: I do not understand exactly which part of $F$ you consider as the 'differentiable' part, and which one you consider as the 'proxable' part. Please elaborate.

Comment: f(X,Y) is considered as differentiable part where as the remaining part is proxable. My problem is how to handle multiple variable norms for a proximal gradient descent.

Comment: Could you specify which matrix norm are you referring to? Is it Frobenius?

Comment: Yes it is Frobenius norm.